# how to add time/duration from database using php

Tags: php, database, datetime, addition

I have this data from data base.

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id |     date time        |  duration |
+----+------------+----------+-----------
| 3  | 2012-12-20  09:28:53 |     ?     |
| 1  | 2012-12-20  19:44:10 |    ?      |
| 2  | 2012-12-23  16:25:15 |           |
| 4  | 2012-12-23  18:26:16 |           |
| 4  | 2012-12-24  08:01:27 |           |
| 5  | 2012-12-29  20:57:33 |           | 
| 5  | 2012-12-29  20:57:33 |           | 
+----+------------+----------+------------
```

- duration for id `#1` should be equal to the date id `#2` - id #1
- duration for id `#2` should be equal to the date id `#3` - id #2

While if the `id` is the same, it will be added.

Sorry this is only in my mind, still very new in php so I don't know how to start.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

edited sorted by date. duration or total time for 1st record =  2nd record - 1st record

Comment: Try converting the dates to the internal format (you'll see it as Unix timestamp or something similar). In that format, you can get the difference between two dates/times in seconds by just subtracting them.

Comment: I already  use strtotime to convert but my problem is since this is fetch from data base, how can I put it in duration column across id 1, id 2 and so on. Pls guide me maybe it is nested loop but im still don't know how to do it. Thnks again

Comment: Well, once you do have the times like that, you just subtract the current to the previous one and put them into the corresponding place in the table. Yes, you would need to iterate through the table, and do it per row.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for. You want to change value of duration of id#1, id#2 or what?

Comment: I only have the table from my query(fetch_array) but without the duration because I don't know how to put it. Im still new in looping, so I really don't know how to put it across.

Comment: duration= latest date - previousdate if the id is the same, it will be added for total duration. Thnk for help again

Comment: Is this what you're asking for? `SELECT TableName.id, TableName.date, Sum(TableName.duration) AS SumOfDuration FROM TableName GROUP BY TableName.id, TableName.date`
Replace `TableName` with your one. This SQL query sums all fields that have the same `id` and `date`. (I'm not sure about adding dates/times, will `Sum()` work properly?) I'm also not sure what you have in mind writing "duration for id #1 should be equal to the date id #2 - id #1" but you may try to use this statement as a basis.

Comment: @Voitcus. Thks for reply but since this is timestamp, I can't change the table. 2nd this is actually sorted by date. The id  is like a name of process. I want to get how long the duration for each process.

Comment: You don't change the table. `SELECT` query is for retrieving data from your database. Order doesn't matter. Somewhere you take your records to PHP and maybe you should use this query, I don't know, I still don't get what it means "duration should be equal to date"

Comment: @Voitcus I can't use the sum since this depends on the datetime format. 1st record duration = 2nd record timestamp - 1st record timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly there is something which is called `id=3` and it starts at "2012-12-20  09:28:53" then it ends at "2012-12-20  19:44:10" and in the same second something `id=3` starts and you want to know how long everything lasts?

I would do a loop for all records, but I'd start from ending (in SQL: `...ORDER BY date_time DESC`), assuming that end of the last (ie. `id=5` which started on 2012-12-29  20:57:33) is now, then I calculate duration as substraction of dates (beginning and end), then I would take event beginning as end of the previous one and so on.

An example (not tested):

```
$end=now();
$dbh=new PDO(...); // here you need to connect to your db, see manual
while($record=$dbh->query('SELECT id, datetime FROM table_name ORDER BY datetime DESC')->fetchObject()){
  $start=$record->datetime;
  echo $duration=$end-$start; // convert $end and $start to timestamps, if necessary
  $end=$start; // here I say that next (in sense of loop, in fact it is previous) record will end at the moment where this record started
}
```

This doesn't sum because I don't know how are you going to store your data, but I think you will manage with this.

EDITED

At the beginning I define an array:

```
$durations=array(); // this will hold durations
$ids=array();  // this will hold `id`-s
$last_id=-1; // the value that is not existent
```

Then the code follows and instead of `echo` I put this:

```
$duration=$end-$start;
if($last->id==$record->id){ // is this the same record as before?
  $durations[count($durations)-1]->duration+=$duration; // if yes, add to previous value
  }
else { // a new id
  $durations[]=$duration; // add new duration to array of durations
  $ids[]=$record->id; // add new id to array of ids
  $last_id=$record->id; // update $last_id 
  }
```

and then `$end=$start` as above.

To view all durations and ids simply

```
for($i=0;$i<count($durations);$i++){
  echo 'id='.$ids[$i].', duration='.$durations[$i].'<br />';
  }
```

Note these tables are in reverse order.

Comment: This is actually my problem. I don't know how to get data for duration. How can I subtract the previous time to later time. I'm not sure if there's a need to make in array. I'm still really a newbie in this php.